# Design Pattern for Make a Mind Mapping Application

Tags: design-patterns, mindmapping

What is the best suitable pattern for making a Mind Mapping Style Application like MindMiester, XMind, etc. Composite or Decorator or another pattern ?

Comment: Who said you'd need exactly one design pattern for a given piece of software? How about, you know, checking out the problems (in a very broad sense) such software has to solve and devising solutions to them, using as many or few design patterns as appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns are for solving algorithmic/object oriented problems in code/library/framework level when creating software, not for purposing the software itself.